# Advice about about staying in South Africa

Tags: visas, covid-19, south-africa, quarantine

I have been in Cape Town on an extended visa for 14 months now (visa extensions were automatic due to the pandemic) the government's last extension expires on 31st March.

Do I have the option to extend the visa again as South Africa, as stated by the UK, is a red list country and if I travel back to the UK on 30th March I would have to go into a quarantine hotel in the UK costing £1,750 which neither myself or my family can afford.

I am living with my fiancé. We were due to get married in Feb 21, then we changed it to April 21, now the date has changed to Aug 21 when hopefully my family will be able to travel out to SA to the wedding. If the restrictions are still in place the wedding date will change again. I really need help on what my options are please.

Could I go to Namibia for a week then come back to Cape Town and have another 90 days visa. Would that work?

Comment: Don't forget staying in South Africa or flying to the UK are not your only options. You can fly and stay in a different country for 2 weeks if you want to avoid paying £1750 to the UK.

Comment: @kiradotee Is there a risk of being denied entry on return to SA in that scenario, after such a long stay as a visitor?

Comment: I was only due to be in South Africa for 6 months (90 days plus an approved visa extension) but due to the pandemic and restrictions the SA government kept extending the tourist visa stay.

Comment: I fully intend to go back to the UK as soon as the hotel quarantine is lifted.

Comment: @Traveller the point is to stay in a country that's not in the UK's red list (currently 35 countries on that list) for 10 days so that OP can safely return to the UK without paying for a quarantine hotel. As didn't seem like he intends in staying in South Africa. Obviously of course he still might need to go through PCR tests or meet other requirements to travel to that 3rd country. But likely cheaper than £1750.

Comment: @kiradotee The OP asks about going to Namibia for a week, then back to Cape Town for another 90 day visa. Plus there’s no guarantee any 3rd country won’t be put on the UK’s red list while the OP is there.